# How can I disable an ActiveX frame?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, activex, frame

Within Excel I have three frames, one of these frames contains check boxes. Based upon user selection, I want to be able to enable and disable these ActiveX check boxes, assuming that enabling/disabling the frame would be the most efficient way of doing this I tried the following code:

```
Dim oOle As OLEObject, ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
   For Each oOle In ws.OLEObjects
       oOle.Enabled = False
   Next oOle
Next ws
```

But this disabled all the frames whereas I only want to disable `Frame2`, can someone please help?

Comment: `If oOle.Name = "Frame2" Then...?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
    Dim Ctrl As Control

    For Each Ctrl In Frame2.Controls
         Ctrl.Enabled = False ' Disable the controls
    Next

    For Each Ctrl In Frame2.Controls
         Ctrl.Enabled = True ' Enable the controls
    Next
```